# viewbag object pass to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I m trying to pass a object to view with viewbag and pass it to javascript parameter in the view
But when comes to assign object to script value it looks like string likes its namespace

in controller:

```
 public ACCIDENT_REPORTS getFilledReportWithEntitiesById(int accidentReport_id)
        {
            ACCIDENT_REPORTS report = new ACCIDENT_REPORTS();
            report = context.ACCIDENT_REPORTS.Include("ACCR_ENTITIES").Where(a => a.ID == accidentReport_id).FirstOrDefault();
            return report;
        }

    ViewBag.Report = DatabaseContext.Current.AccidentReportingRepository.getFilledReportWithEntitiesById(id); //its okey, all data in viewbag
```

in view:

```
<script>
    debugger
    var data = '@ViewBag.Report';
</script>
// in debugger value looks like; var data = 'Application.Database.ACCIDENT_REPORTS;
```

Why it looks like string ? how can I pass contents of viewbag to javascript value

here is my entity object return type:

```
public partial class ACCIDENT_REPORTS
    {
        public ACCIDENT_REPORTS()
        {
            this.ACCR_ENTITIES = new HashSet<ACCR_ENTITIES>();
        }

        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public decimal FACILITY_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> START_DATE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> END_DATE { get; set; }
        public string TITLE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ACCIDENT_TYPE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> REPORTED_UNDER { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SEVESOII_STATUS { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> INDUSTRIAL_ACTIVITY { get; set; }
        public string REASON_FOR_REPORTING { get; set; }
        public string ACCIDENT_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string SITE_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string UNIT_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string CAUSES_OF_ACCIDENT { get; set; }
        public string CONSEQUENCES { get; set; }
        public string EMERGENCY_RESPONSE { get; set; }
        public string LESSONS_LEARNED { get; set; }
        public string ACCIDENTS_INVOLVING { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> REPORT_STATUS { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ACCR_ENTITIES> ACCR_ENTITIES { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type *returned* by `getFilledReportWithEntitiesById()`?

Presumably, it's a `Application.Database.ACCIDENT`.  All the view engine does is invoke `.ToString()` on what it's given.  And the default implementation for `.ToString()` on any reference type (any child of `object` basically) is to return the type name.

If you want a custom string representation of your type, then that type needs to override `.ToString()`.  For example:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}", ID, Name);
}
```

If the object has an `ID` property and a `Name` property then its string representation would then be those values separated by a hyphen (with spaces in between).  However you want to structure the string representation of your object would be done within this method.

Conversely, if you don't want it to be a *string*, but want the JavaScript code to use it as an *object*, then you want to serialize it to JSON.  Something like this:

```
var data = @Json.Encode(ViewBag.Report);
```

(You might need to tweak that a little bit, I don't have an environment handy to test it.  But you get the idea... To use it as an object in JavaScript code it needs to be serialized to a JavaScript object literal.)

Comment: it returns an enttiy object. I have also tried to serialize but inside json it also looks namespace string :S

Comment: @user3347326: "An entity object" doesn't really tell me anything.  It appears to be a custom type (though not following C# naming conventions, but that's not a big deal).  How did you try serializing it to JSON and what was the result?  What is the structure of the object being serialized?

Comment: var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Report)'); this the way I always use and Works fine parsing method but now contents of raw looks like 'Application.Database.ACCIDENT_REPORTS' value looks namespace string I think its related with you said about C# namin how can I fix this ? (I edited the question)

Comment: @user3347326: The problem with that attempt is that you're still just invoking the string representation of `ViewBag.Report`.  As I said in my answer, the default string representation of an object is its type name.  `Html.Raw()` is going to take that type name and emit it to the client.  So `JSON.parse()` is just trying to parse, well, the type name.  In order to emit the *object* to the client-side code you need to JSON-encode it (or provide a custom `.ToString()` implementation on the object itself which does this).  The client-side code can't do anything with the type name.

Comment: you mean I must encode it in the controller than parse it in the view ?

Comment: @user3347326: No, this can (and should) be done in the view, as suggested in my answer.  The `@Json.Encode(ViewBag.Report)` part is server-side code in the view, everything around it is client-side code in the view.  Combining the two would mean that the server-side code would emit some value to the client-side code, in this case a JavaScript object.

Comment: var data = '@Json.Encode(ViewBag.Report)' when I tried it it throws an error page with message: "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Application.Database.ACCIDENT_REPORTS'." what does it mean I saw it before :S

Comment: @user3347326: It means that the type's properties internally reference itself.  For example, the object may have a property of another object, which internally has a property of the original object.  You can use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the object's properties to specify which properties shouldn't be included when serializing it to JSON.  The alternative to that would be either removing the properties (probably not ideal, especially if other things use them) or writing a custom serialization, which is a bit more work.

Comment: its ok now I got it. both of them have foreign keys each other.. this is why happens circular reference error.. thank you. I can check your last answer as solved if you want. Thank you again

Answer (score -1):

this is the real answer

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PlaceStatistic.ToArray()))
```